How do I fix Windows Update Error 0x800706f4 and sound issue ("Failed to play test tone")?
I'm facing two separate issues with my Windows 11 PC: a Windows Update error (0x800706f4) and a sound problem. Every time I try to install updates, the update process fails with the error code 0x800706f4. I’ve tried common fixes like restarting my PC and using the Windows Update Troubleshooter, but nothing has worked.
Additionally, I’m experiencing sound issues where the Test Tone in the "Configure Speakers" window won’t play, showing the error message "Impossible de lire la tonalité de test". The sound drivers are up to date, but I still can't fix the sound problem.
For the Windows Update error 0x800706f4, I’ve tried the following:
Restarted my PC multiple times.
Ran the Windows Update Troubleshooter, expecting it to identify and resolve the issue automatically.
Followed various YouTube tutorials, hoping they would provide a solution.
Despite these efforts, the error persists, and updates still fail to install.
For the sound issue, I checked my sound drivers, confirmed they are up to date, and expected the 'Test Tone' to play after clicking the 'Test' button in the "Configure Speakers" window. However, instead of sound, I get the error "Impossible de lire la tonalité de test". I expected the test sound to work but still cannot get any audio output.

For sound issue ("Failed to play test tone") do the following steps:
Simply what you need to do is:
Press [Windows Key / Command Key] and R (Win + R), then there will popup a field
In that you write services.msc and press enter
Search "Windows Audio" and stop that process and start it again
Then the problem is solved.

Alternatively without using Win + R, you can go by Task Manager to the tab Services (you might need to press on bottom left, more details in order for those tabs to show up) and then go from there and stop Windows Audio and start it again. A PC restart won't help, since it probably caches some data and remains in the failing state.
Or if above solution not works then Open Device Manager, delete the sound devices (but keep the drivers).
Reboot.  Sound finally works! Or Install the latest driver for Realtek High Definition Audio

and for Windows Update error (0x800706f4) One of the following step will sort out the problem:
 1. Repair corrupted system 
 2. Boot window manually
 3. Resetting computer's BIOS
 4. DO SFC scan
 5. Troubleshoot to fix automatically

0x800706f4 is a null reference pointer exception. Based solely on that I would guess that the pairing of your fingerprint / PIN to the account in question is busted. Try logging in with a password and removing, then resetting the fingerprint & PIN settings.
